# Unable to create transactionManager (JTA) bean using Spring 2.5.6 on JBOSS EAP 6.3

Tags: spring, jta, jboss6.x, spring-transactions, transactionmanager

I'm getting this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'wsJtaTm' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]:
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class
[org.springframework.transaction.jta.JotmFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: stub class initialization failed
```

I'm using the following piece of code to create `txnmanager` bean for Jboss
Datasource and JNDI correctly loading and configured.

**applicationcontext.xml**

```
<bean id="wsJtaTm" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JotmFactoryBean" /> 
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="userTransaction" ref="wsJtaTm" />

    </bean>
```

What is wrong with my code?